# Interchange summation order in the limit of number of elements going to $\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence, divergent-series

Considering the sum $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_{ij}$, in general we are not allowed to interchange the summation order (i.e. pass to $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{ij}$) but some more hypothesis are required to allow the change of order (e.g., by Fubini Theorem, we are allowed if $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} |a_{ij}|<\infty$).

Consider now the sum $\sum_{i=0}^{N}\sum_{j=0}^{L} a_{ij}$ , $N=cL$ , $c \in \mathbb{N}$. Our sum doesn't respect Fubini hypothesis, i.e. $\sum_{i=0}^{N=\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{L=\infty} |a_{ij}|=\infty$.

If now we consider the limit sum $\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{N}\sum_{j=0}^{L} a_{ij}$, are we allowed then to interchange the summation order, since $\sum_{i=0}^{N}\sum_{j=0}^{L} |a_{ij}|< \infty$  $\forall N<\infty$?

In other words when can we say that

$\lim_{L\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{cL}\sum_{j=0}^{L} a_{ij} = \lim_{L\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j=0}^{L}\sum_{i=0}^{cL} a_{ij}$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "we are not interested in the value at the exact point, but only in his surroundings"? The value of what? What exact point? What surroundings?

Comment: Are uou asking whether $\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{i=0}^{N}\sum_{j=0}^{L} a_{ij}=\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{L} \sum_{i=0}^{N}a_{ij}$? That is of course true (provided that either one of the two limits exists), since $ \sum_{i=0}^{N}\sum_{j=0}^{L} a_{ij}= \sum_{j=0}^{L} \sum_{i=0}^{N}a_{ij}$

Comment: @IosifPinelis, thank for your comments; I removed the not clear sentence to go directly at the point of the question

Answer (score 1):

*Comment.*  I think it should work like this.  Let
$\alpha = \sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_{ij}, \beta = \sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_{ij}$ both exist.  Assume $\alpha < \beta$.  Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exist sequences
$(N_k)_{k=1}^\infty$, $(M_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ so that $N_k \to \infty$, $M_k \to \infty$ and
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{N_k}\sum_{j=0}^{k} a_{ij} < \alpha+\varepsilon
\\
\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{M_k}\sum_{j=0}^{k} a_{ij} > \beta-\varepsilon
$$

But we cannot assume that $N_k, M_k$ grow more slowly that $ck$ for some constant $c$, nor that they grow more rapidly than $ck$ for some $c>1$.

Comment: If you try to prove what I wrote here, you will find it is wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your reasoning;Can you give some more detail? My doubt is for the specific case in which the number of terms diverge in the same way for the 2 index (see end of the question), such that we have a single limit for the whole double sum: is this a sufficient element to reverse the order? if yes why is this the case?